# Perform Joins in O(n) time?

Tags: algorithm, database-design, data-structures, database

is there a way to Join 2 tables in linear time? I heard this can be done by having another data structure (Hashtable), but I'm not sure how this can be done. I was always wondering a Join will involve a cross-product and hence it is O(n^2).

Comment: check this one http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hash_join

Comment: [A really interesting book on this general topic.](http://oreilly.com/catalog/9780596005733)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Algorithm:

Loop through table A. Hash all Items, Add them to the Join array.
Loop through table B, check each item if it's in the hash table (Check - O(1)), if not, add to the Join table.

Answer (score 2):

If there are indexes available on columns used in the join, it's linear because the indexes allow an in-order traversal of both tables. (That's not counting the amortized index cost, of course.)

A hash join will be sort-of linear, though the hashing itself isn't free, and when the keys involved are long then the costs also go up.

Comment: OK - note that while indexes make it possible, in principle, to do a linear-time join, a server may decide to do a hash join if statistics indicate that one of the effective tables is much smaller than the other.

Comment: Yes, the size of the 2 tables have to be checked for better efficiency.

Answer (score 2):

It depends on the type of join. A cross join is always going to be O(n^2) since it has to produce O(n^2) records. An equi-join can be done with better complexity (O(n log(n)) or perhaps even amortized O(n)), provided right data structures are employed.

Comment: I was looking for the time complexity for a natural join

Comment: The type of join doesn't matter. Take two tables with disjoint columns add a common dummy column with value 0 for each record. The complexity of natural join is still quadratic, and therefore is worst case estimate.

Answer (score 2):

You can join two tables in close to O(n) by using a hash table to look up records in one table based on the id of the other table.

Well, actually the operation will be close to O(n+m), where *n* and *m* are the number of items in the two tables. You would first loop through the records in one table to build a hash table from the key in that table, then you would loop through the other table to look up a match in the hash table for each of the records.

Looking up an item in a hash table is not an O(1) operation, but it's close. With more data you will have a few more hash collisions, so some of the lookups need to do more than one comparison.

Answer (score 1):

Major db vendors deprecated hash indexes long-long time ago. Therefore, joining 2 tables in O(max(n,m)) time is something that really doesn't matter in practice. With standard B-tree indexes join complexity is O(min(n,m)*log(max(n,m)).