# Why is the complexity of hash join O(n+m)?

Tags: database, join, time-complexity

After I did some search on the web, I found that the complexity of Hash Join algorithm of joining two tables is said to be O(N+M), where N and M are the number of tuples of two tables.

I wonder why is it O(N+M), in stead of O(N*M) in the worst case?

As far as I know, Hash Join is an implementation of equi join: given two tables R and S, it is to select tuples t from their cross-product R*S where t[R.A] = t[S.A], A is a common attribute of R and S.

Notes:
1) I wonder if the complexity is O(N+M), especially when the data values are **not unique** in the joining attribute (i.e. we are not joining on key attributes).
2) Note that joining attribute A may or may not be a key.

Comment: do you have a link to where this is said?

Comment: Big Os aren't that helpful and misleading in databases, the main overhead is the network/disk latency

Comment: @SleimanJneidi If we assume that the entire hash join takes place in memory, then would the OP be more meaningful?

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen Yes. Especially since the hash table can avoid a great deal of disk accesses by excluding tuples without actually reading and then comparing all their values over and over again.

Comment: @Thilo for example, [1] http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2065754/is-there-any-general-rule-on-sql-query-complexity-vs-performance and [2] http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5557964/perform-joins-in-on-time

Comment: @SleimanJneidi let us just consider from the theoretical point of view first...

Answer (score 3):

The search algorithm is basically:

1. hash each tuple from R (O(n))
2. hash each tuple from S (O(m))

   2.1 each time a tuple from S is hashed, look it up in the hashes of R (O(1))

   2.2 only if a matching hash in found for R, compare the actual tuple values (O(1))

Hence, you only need to compute one hash per tuple (n+m) and do m hash lookups, which ideally are O(1) each.

Of course, if the hash function does not fit the actual data, or the hash table is too small, the hash lookup will still be O(1), but you may have to do many full tuple comparisons most of which yield `false`. Thus, the *worst* worst case, for a *worst case* hash table, approaches O(n*m) again.

Comment: I also suspect that if you cannot do the entire procedure in memory, then the performance will also deviate from `O(N+M)`.

Comment: I don't think so. Remember that O(n) = O(c*n). Hence, for the O notation it does not make any difference if the access to each single entry takes 1ms or 100ms.

Comment: @HannoBinder Thanks for the answer! My confusion comes from the step 2.2 above: if there are many tuples in R which can all match a tuple t1 from S, it should not be O(1). For example, in the extreme case, every tuples in R can match t1, then the complexity for 2.2 would be O(n), n is the size of R. Am I wrong some where?

Comment: The complexity is for sure O(m+n) when the joining attribute A are both keys for the table R and S, right?

Comment: It fully depends on the hash function and the size of the hash table. A badly selected hash function may project many/all tuples onto a single hash value, just as if they were the same values. A perfect hash function will create a 1:1 relation between hash value and tuple. OTOH it depends on whether we're talking strictly about *relations*, which are *sets* of tuples, hence no duplicates.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen Thanks for the reminder! But I may have to apologize that I couldn't agree with the answer. For the worst case, I did not mean that it comes from a badly selected hash function. I was confused about the case that: 1) there are duplicates in the common column A of R and S ; 2) they are still relations since there can be distinct tuples sharing the same values on attribute A. For example, R(A, B)={(1, 2), (1, 3), (2, 3)} amd S(A, C)={(1, 4), (1, 5), (2, 3)}.

Comment: For example, R(A, B)={(1, 1), (1, 2), ..., (1, 100)} and S(A, C)={(1, 4), (1, 5)}. There will be 200 results for "select * from R, S where R.A=S.A", and as a consequence, the complexity should be m*n = 100 * 2.

Comment: I think your argument is valid, and so is the conclusion of a worst-case complexity of n*m. I believe I need to do some read-up to find the assumptions made for the "n+m" statement.

Comment: @HannoBinder Thanks! I will dig up more about it too.